# Error signing android app on phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to sign an android app in phonegap build.

I'm using the following command which succeeds in gennerating a keystore file but when I upload to phonegap build I get the following **error**:

> Error - Invalid keystore format

This is the command I am using on Windows:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\keytool" -genkeypair -alias
>   my_alias_name -keystore my_keystore_name.keystore -keypass ******
>   -storepass ****** -validity 10000 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storetype pkcs12 -v

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the -storetype pkcs12 flag. When I removed this and used the defaults it worked perfectly.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When I've hit this error in the past it was because of an alias/password issue. To test it, try generating a new alias/password and signing your APK with that. If it works, you've isolated your problem.

Comment: Turns out it was the -storetype pkcs12 key that was causing it to fail. When I removed this and it ran with the defaults this solved the problem.